# Brain tree paypal integration failure

Tags: java, paypal-sandbox, braintree, braintree-sandbox

currently am working with payment gateway using brain tree. When i hit paypal fake nonce "fake-paypal-one-time-nonce" like the above on get an error message **Processor Network Unavailable - Try Again** but braintree nonce are working. I integrate my paypal with brain tree i use the following java code to hit

thanks.

```
    TransactionRequest request = new TransactionRequest();
    CustomerRequest customerRequest = request.customer();
    customerRequest.email(nonceDetails.getString("email"))
            .firstName(nonceDetails.getString("name"))
            .phone(nonceDetails.getString("mobileNumber"));

    request.amount(new BigDecimal(nonceDetails.getFloat("amount")))
            .paymentMethodNonce(nonceDetails.getString("nonce"))//<-- Here I put my nonce 
            .options()
            .submitForSettlement(true)
            .paypal()
            .done();


    try {
        Result<Transaction> result = bt.transaction().sale(request);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            Transaction transaction = result.getTarget();
            future.complete(transaction);
        } else if (result.getTransaction() != null) {
            Transaction transaction = result.getTransaction();
            logger.error("Error in BrainTreeGateWay::paymentConfirmationWithNonce - " + transaction.toString());
            future.fail(result.getErrors().toString());
        } else {
            for (ValidationError error : result.getErrors().getAllDeepValidationErrors()) {
                logger.error("Error in BrainTreeGateWay::paymentConfirmationWithNonce - " + error.getMessage());
            }
            future.fail(result.getErrors().toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you are using v3 of our JavaScript SDK and have your PayPal sandbox account enabled within your Braintree sandbox then you will need to receive a nonce directly from Braintree rather than using a test nonce value.

Since the [linked PayPal testing flow](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live#linked-paypal-testing) is intended to test the full functionality of your PayPal integration the PayPal test nonce values will no longer be compatible in your sandbox.

I would recommend emailing in to Braintree Support so we can take a look at your sandbox setup and see if this is the case, or if something else is causing you to receive the 3000 failure response.